# Question about Probability Problem Potentially Involving Binomial Model

Tags: probability

Suppose an airport metal detector catches a person with metal $99\%$ of the time. That is, it misses detecting a person with metal $1\%$ of the time. Assume independence of people carrying metal. What is the probability that the first person missed (not detected) is among the first $50$ metal-carrying persons scanned?

What I did: $\binom{50}{1} (.01)(0.99)^{49} = 0.3056$

However...the answer seems to be $0.395$?

Comment: This is the probability that the first sucess (missing metal) is at 50 or less. Do you know about the geometric distribution?

Comment: Why would it be the geometric? The geometric concerns itself with how many fails until a success, and then it stops, but in this case, the success can be anyone among the first 50

Comment: Exactly, it is the probability that the first sucess is at person 1 + the probability that the first sucess is at person 2 ... etc. Thus you use the cdf of a geometric distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the first time you get a success. Where a success is defined as missing a detection. Therefore $X$ has a geometric distribution with success parameter 0.01. Thus, you seek the probability that $X \leq 50$. This is 0.395 as desired.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the question sound like if it were binomial?

Comment: @quantitative "What is the probability that there are at least 3 misses during the first 50 people carrying metal?"

Comment: It could ask something like: "in a group of 50 people carrying metal through, what is the probability that exactly one person carries metal through and doesn't get caught?" In which case the answer is $.3056$ from your first calculation.

Comment: @quantitative Interestingly you could use binomial for this (less intuitively) as this is 1 - the probability that there are exactly 0 detections during the first 50.